# How to make the iOS images slider like that on ipad app store ?

Tags: image, ipad

I would like to make the image slider like that on ipad mini app store ?

Please check the link:

http://www.thefullsignal.com/news/1665618/best_ipad_mini_apps_to_get_started_with.html

Comment: Which slider exactly? There are a few sliders in your link...

Comment: The first one the one with the image "NBA game time"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking  for icarousel Check [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).